# How Apple App gets YouTube authorization

Tags: ios, youtube, audit

I have an playing video app in Apple. but Apple replies are not authorized. The reply is:
5.2.3 - Facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media from third party sources without explicit authorization from those sources.
The app has passed Apple audits before adding YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property), streaming of videos may also violate their terms of use, so it isn't allowed. So unfortunately it sounds like you will either need to get YouTube's permission, or just remove YouTube streaming from your app.

Comment: How to get YouTube's permission. I didn't find any information about YouTube's permission on the official website.

Comment: Unfortunately, YouTube most likely won't give permission. As they already have their own app for watching their videos, they probably don't want to compete with other apps.

Comment: But App Store still has some app with YouTube functions, how do they get authorization?